# How do I add header attributes to data rows?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sed, dataset

I have a weather dataset obtained from [igra2 weather dataset](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/igra/data/data-por/)

A typical part of a file looks like:

```
#ICXUAE05424 1909 04 22 99 0935    6          erac-hud  657000      -180000
30 -9999  -9999   100 -9999 -9999 -9999   120    49
30 -9999  -9999   350 -9999 -9999 -9999   119   110
30 -9999  -9999   750-9999 -9999 -9999   149    97
30 -9999  -9999  1250-9999 -9999 -9999   136   123
30 -9999  -9999  1750-9999 -9999 -9999   104   121
30 -9999  -9999  2250-9999 -9999 -9999   117   171
#ICXUAE05424 1909 04 22 99 1820    3          erac-hud  657000      -180000
30 -9999  -9999   100 -9999 -9999 -9999   120    53
30 -9999  -9999   350A -9999 -9999 -9999   111    69
30 -9999  -9999   750B-9999 -9999 -9999   102    55
#ICXUAE05424 1909 04 23 99 0845    5          erac-hud  657000      -180000
30 -9999  -9999   100 -9999 -9999 -9999    31     9
30 -9999  -9999   350 -9999 -9999 -9999   102    62
30 -9999  -9999   750 -9999 -9999 -9999   103   132
30 -9999  -9999  1250 -9999 -9999 -9999    98   120
30 -9999  -9999  1750 -9999 -9999 -9999   101   100
```

I need to preprocess the data by appending some(or all) of the header attributes to its data rows, and then convert it into a csv file.
How do I achieve this using **sed** in linux bash, if not Python **Pandas**
The output csv file should look something of the form:

```
lvl12,etime,press,gph,temp,rh,dpdp,wdir,wspd,hour,lattitude,longitude
21,-9999,96900A,234,270A,742,-9999,-9999,-9999,12,316333,748667
20,-9999,95000,-9999,290A,484,-9999,-9999,-9999,12,316333,748667
20,-9999,88700,-9999,290A,454,-9999,-9999,-9999,12,316333,748667
10,-9999,85000,1384A,260A,446,-9999,-9999,-9999,12,316333,748667
10,-9999,70000,3055A,130A,506,-9999,-9999,-9999,12,316333,748667
20,-9999,58400,-9999,0A,690,-9999,-9999,-9999,12,316333,748667
20,-9999,55900,-9999,0A,312,-9999,-9999,-9999,12,316333,748667
10,-9999,50000,5772A,-65A-9999,-9999,320,850,,12,316333,748667
```

**Additional dataset info:**

The `#` prefixed lines are the headers, the lines that follow is the data.

The Header attributes are:

```
station code, year, month, day, etc
```

The seventh attribute space separated is `npv` and signifies the number of data rows that follow.

The data columns are:

```
lvl12, etime, press, gph, temp, rh, dpdp, wdir, wspd
```

Comment: It would be better if your sample input and sample output actually matched, so we could see how the data maps from one to the other.

Comment: In `awk`, check if the first character is `#` and save the field values in variables. On other lines, append those variables to the line by assigning to `$10`, `$11`, and `$12`, and then print the line.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to parse the file manually line by line noting where the headers are.

I am assuming that data such as `750-9999` actually has a space in it `750 -9999`? If this is not the case then a fixed width approach would be needed:

This can be done with just Python's CSV library as follows:

```
import csv

header = ["lvl12", "etime", "press", "gph", "temp", "rh", "dpdp", "wdir", "wspd", "hour", "lattitude", "longitude"]    
data = []

with open('weather.txt', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    for row in csv_input:
        if row[0].startswith('#'):
            header = row
        else:
            csv_output.writerow(row + [header[5]] + header[-2:])
```

Or if you want to also make use of Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = []

with open('weather.txt', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

    for row in csv_input:
        if row[0].startswith('#'):
            header = row
        else:
            data.append(row + [header[5]] + header[-2:])

columns = ["lvl12", "etime", "press", "gph", "temp", "rh", "dpdp", "wdir", "wspd", "hour", "lattitude", "longitude"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)
```

Giving you:

```
   lvl12  etime  press   gph   temp     rh   dpdp wdir wspd  hour lattitude longitude
0     30  -9999  -9999   100  -9999  -9999  -9999  120   49  0935    657000   -180000
1     30  -9999  -9999   350  -9999  -9999  -9999  119  110  0935    657000   -180000
2     30  -9999  -9999   750  -9999  -9999  -9999  149   97  0935    657000   -180000
3     30  -9999  -9999  1250  -9999  -9999  -9999  136  123  0935    657000   -180000
4     30  -9999  -9999  1750  -9999  -9999  -9999  104  121  0935    657000   -180000
..   ...    ...    ...   ...    ...    ...    ...  ...  ...   ...       ...       ...
9     30  -9999  -9999   100  -9999  -9999  -9999   31    9  0845    657000   -180000
10    30  -9999  -9999   350  -9999  -9999  -9999  102   62  0845    657000   -180000
11    30  -9999  -9999   750  -9999  -9999  -9999  103  132  0845    657000   -180000
12    30  -9999  -9999  1250  -9999  -9999  -9999   98  120  0845    657000   -180000
13    30  -9999  -9999  1750  -9999  -9999  -9999  101  100  0845    657000   -180000

[14 rows x 12 columns]
```

Tested using Python 3.x. If you are using Python 2.x, change the following:

```
with open('weather.txt', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
```